# Which class loader is used by JNI calls in native code?

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface, classloader, native

I have `A.jar` which uses jna to call into some native code `B.dll`, which in turn uses JNI to call into `C.jar`.

The class in `A.jar` which does all the jna calls to `B.dll` is loaded with a `CustomClassLoader` which has `C.jar` and `A.jar` added to its URL list - `A.jar`'s system class loader does not have `C.jar` in its URL list.

When the native code in `B.dll` calls `env->FindClass('some/class/in/c.jar')` it can not find the class. If I remove the `CustomClassLoader` and add `C.jar` to the URL list of `A.jar`'s system class loader, `env->FindClass('some/class/in/c.jar')` is able to find the class. However, I would really really like the class in `A.jar` to be loaded with the `CustomClassLoader`, because when the execution arrives in `C.jar` I do not want that code to have the same class loader as `A.jar`.

So, is it possible to somehow ensure that when `B.dll` runs the JNI call `env->FindClass('some/class/in/c.jar/')` the `CustomClassLoader` is being used?

Comment: If you don't want C.jar to have the same class loader as A.jar why are you adding it to the same classloader's URL list? The answer here is to have the custom classloader have the system class loader as a delegate, and let the system class loader fin C.jar. But it's hard to understand from your description why it doesn't work now, assuming your description is accurate.

Comment: So there is a class Foo in A.jar which does JNA calls to B.dll, and I want this class to be loaded with a custom class loader, such that when B.dll uses JNI to call into C.jar, that custom class loader will be used. Foo still have to use other resources in A.jar which is why A.jar has to be in the URL list of the custom class loader which loads Foo. However, when I try this it doesn't seem like C.jar gets loaded with the custom class loader when it is called by B.dll through JNI calls.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, [findClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) documentation states:

> FindClass locates the class loader associated with the current native
>   method; that is, the class loader of the class that declared the
>   native method.

One solution to your problem can be sending the CustomClassLoader instance in a method parameter to the C code and cache it there, whenever you need to do class lookup you can use that classloader instance (call the method findClass).